# Is "looking to" considered proper English?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it proper, grammatical English to say,

> "Are you looking to move?"

Should it not be:

1. "Are you interested in moving?"
2. "Are you thinking of moving?"

Comment: I don't know about proper, but it is colloquial. I will say that in my neck of the woods at least, _looking to_ is a "stronger" feeling than just _thinking_ or _having an interest_ of/in doing something.

Comment: It's definitely idiomatic in the US. Wouldn't be considered "formal", but would not draw the slightest raised eyebrow in ordinary conversation.

Comment: @VampDuc -- And the construction "rolls off the tongue" more smoothly, since it uses the "normal" tense of the object verb vs using the -ing tense.

Comment: "Look" is featured in many idioms: "look up" means research but "look up to" means respect, "look down on" means disrespect or disapprove, "look after" means care for, "look out" means beware, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+to) site includes citations from the *Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms*, *The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms*, and *The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs* with meanings of to plan or expect something to happen. There's no special indication as to the informality or correctness of the expression. There would be nothing surprising or even particularly informal about the phrase in (American) business meetings:  "We're looking to increase revenues by 200 per cent over the next three years".  The frequency of usage may vary regionally, but I can't imagine a speaker of American English who would be surprised or "put off" by this usage.  Similarly, "looking at" is not infrequently used to mean considering or contemplating an option or possibility: "Are they looking at eliminating staff?"

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly grammatical. "Are you [gerund] [infinitive]?" is a common enough pattern. So much that I find it hard to answer any objection because I can't see what the objection might be.

*Look* meaning "plan" or "expect" is a long-standing sense.

> … and by midnight look to hear further from me. — "All's Well That Ends Well", Act III, Scene 6.
>
> Come, go with us; we'll look to that anon: — "The Comedy of Errors", Act V, Scene 1.